# How do I Read SAML response from AzureAD?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I have created a sign in request using WsFederation like so:

```
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" }, WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
```

I get a saml RequestSecurityTokenResponse from AzureAD with my claims listed correctly.

How do I get the details from the response? I have tried the following so far:

```
  ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name").Value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   string strVarCallResult = string.Empty;  
            string ClaimUserID = string.Empty;  
            string ClaimEmployeeID = string.Empty;  

            try  
            {  
                foreach (string s in Request.Params.Keys)  
                {  
                    if (s.ToString() == "SAMLResponse")  
                    {  
                        rawSamlData = Request.Params[s];  
                        break;  
                    }  
                }  

                byte[] samlData = Convert.FromBase64String(rawSamlData);  

                // read back into a UTF string  
                string samlAssertion = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(samlData);  

                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();  
                XmlNamespaceManager xMan = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);  
                xMan.AddNamespace("saml2p", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");  
                xMan.AddNamespace("saml2", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");  
                xMan.AddNamespace("ds", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");  

                doc.LoadXml(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(samlData));  
                //Response.Write(doc.LastChild.ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[2].ChildNodes[0].InnerXml);  
                XmlNode xNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/saml2p:Response/saml2:Assertion/saml2:Subject/saml2:NameID", xMan);  

                if (xNode != null)  
                {  
                    UserId = xNode.InnerText;  
                    ClaimUserID = xNode.InnerText;  

                }  
    }  
            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  

            }
```

This code block worked for me. For furthermore elaboration please find the link [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/active-directory-sso-in-windows-azure-using-saml-2-0/). Article written by Sankara Krishnan Venugopal.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do not have a param called SAMLResponse

Comment: You can adjust it according to your params

Comment: Ok, mine appears as a saml request in the form data. Not able to get consume it at the moment and I am thinking it may be because the reply url is not the same as my identifier url

Comment: Yes may be so. In ideal case if you want consume the saml response inside your `assertion consumer service`(ACS) url you can use the above code. As per my knowelage you dont have hook on the SAML request. all you will have is the certificate which will be helpful for you to decode the saml response fired to saml assertion consumer service url(ACS)

Comment: I am sending my request with openid. Would this affect anything?

Comment: OpenID is basically for OAuth as per my knowelage right? SAML is different authentication technique

Comment: Yes, anyhow it has seemed to work now sending an oAuth reques, even with SAML as the authentication method on azure

Comment: Happy if it works. I feel that you have mixed up both concepts. Hey would you mind marking this as the correct answer if it helped. Thanks in advance.